# Use SQLite, plist, or something else?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, ios4

This is more of an opinion question than technical.

I am writing a basic app to get into UIKit, MapKit etc.  I want to store some basic information such as location data, some strings etc, nothing crazy and not too many (several hundred).  I wondered if I should go with SQLite or use plist files?  I will release app updates, so don't want anything where data would be lost.

I'm leaning towards SQLite, but wanted to ask the opinion of people in the know first.

If you'd like to know more about the app to help make a decision, just holler. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html). They are simple to use and you can create them on the fly. If the user deletes the app, the prefs will be deleted, but if they simply install a new version on top, the prefs will remain.

Answer (score 0):

A really good method to store persistent data on iOS devices is the Core Data framework.  Check out [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH1-SW1) tutorial for a good introduction.  There is also a good comparison [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875) of the different data storage types.  Hope that helps!