# Storing variables during lifetime of the ios app

Tags: ios, global-variables, application-restart

What happens to the app when it is killed/terminated from the multitasking tray (i.e double click the home button and delete it from there)? And i relaunch the app again by clicking on it? Consider this scenario. I save some variables (global variables) and i save some values to them. I killed/deleted the app from multitasking tray and relaunched it. I no longer have variable values. How can i store them through the entire process of app life cycle and they can be changed when someone changes within the app life cycle. If you need more information please ask. I have been saving the values to a plist file.I created a settings bundle and saving values to them as global variables..is it the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save data even after the app is killed/terminated, you have to use persistent storage. There are a number of different ways to do this. A few of these ways are using NSUserDefaults, plists, or CoreData.

See these links, and try to find out what's best for what you're trying to do.

[iOS persistent storage strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727508/ios-persistent-storage-strategy)

[Use SQLite, plist, or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135232/use-sqlite-plist-or-something-else/5135327#5135327)

You should also check out the iOS development lectures, there's two parts and the first part covers persistent storage in great detail. It's called Effective iPhone App Development. I recommend watching both, but the first part of the first one would answer your questions.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/ios/